# How to get instance name of Azure App Service in .Net Core

Tags: azure, .net-core

I need to get the name or id of the instance that my code is running on at runtime. For example:

MyApp_0 or MyApp_1

How can I do this in .Net Core when it is deployed to an app service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API's method [**Web Apps - Get Instance Process**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getinstanceprocess) And under the **`environment_variables`** you would see **`COMPUTERNAME`**

> [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/instances/{instanceId}/processes/{processId}?api-version=2019-08-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/%7Bname%7D/instances/%7BinstanceId%7D/processes/%7BprocessId%7D?api-version=2019-08-01)

Comment: Is there no way to do it straight from code? It seems very clunky to go through an api when it should be available as part of the apps configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try use `Environment.MachineName`, if that does not work then use `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.IHostIdProvider.GetHostIdAsync`.

The `IHostIdProvider` should be registered by default according the to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#function-app-provided-services), so all you need to do is to inject it and use it.

```
public interface IHostIdProvider
{
    Task<string> GetHostIdAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```